# Add additional "Next" button to a Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, slick.js

does anyone know how to add an additional "Next slide" button to a Slick Slider? I am already using the dots, and the previous & next arrows, but on the first slide I need to add an additional "Next Slide Button" (for design purposes). Suggestions...help...

Basically a button that advances to the next slide (so on tab-slick-index="0" go to tab-slick-index="1"). This button would only show on the first slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Methods section.

**Possible Solution**

Add your button `<button id="nextSlideBtn">Next Slide Button</button>` inside the first slide.

**ES6**

```
const button = document.getElementById('nextSlideBtn');
const nextSlide = (slider) => {
  $(slider).slick('slickNext');
};
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nextSlide(<YOUR SLIDER>);
});
```

**ES5**

```
var button = document.getElementById('nextSlideBtn');
var nextSlide = function nextSlide(slider) {
  $(slider).slick('slickNext');
};
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  return nextSlide(<YOUR SLIDER>);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, not too savy in Javascript, but what would I put as <YOUR SLIDER>? Is this just the class of my slider? i.e. I have: $('.current-slider-1').slick({ {); - would I just add the slider class in this area?

Comment: Yup, that worked... sweet, thanks so much Luis! `var button = document.getElementById('nextSlideBtn');
  var nextSlide = function nextSlide(slider) {
    $(slider).slick('slickNext');
  };
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  return nextSlide('.current-slider-1');
  });`